# How to prove $a+b+c\ge 3$ with the strange condition?

Tags: inequality

> **Problem.** If $x,y,z\ge 0$ which satisfying both constraits $$xyz\ge \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{9};3(xyz)^2-3+2(x^2+y^2+z^2-x^2y^2-y^2z^2-z^2x^2)=0.$$
> Prove that $x+y+z\ge 3.$

I want to ask how to use $3(xyz)^2-3+2(x^2+y^2+z^2-x^2y^2-y^2z^2-z^2x^2)=0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

*Remark.* It is still complicated.

Let $a := x^2, b := y^2, c := z^2$.
The conditions are written as
$$abc \ge \frac{25}{27}, \quad 3abc -3 + 2(a + b + c - ab - bc - ca) = 0. \tag{1}$$
We need to prove that
$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c} \ge 3$.

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$. We can prove that
$$ab \ge 1. \tag{2}$$

Let $p = a + b, q = ab$. Then $p^2 \ge 4q$.

(1) is written as
$$c = \frac{3 + 2q - 2p}{3q + 2 - 2p}, \quad q\cdot  \frac{3 + 2q - 2p}{3q + 2 - 2p} \ge \frac{25}{27}. \tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), we have $3q + 2 - 2p > 0$
and $3 + 2q - 2p > 0$. From (3), we have
$$p \le \frac{27q^2 + 3q - 25}{27q - 25}.$$

We need to prove that
$$f(p) := \sqrt{p + 2\sqrt{q}} + \sqrt{\frac{3 + 2q - 2p}{3q + 2 - 2p}} \ge 3. \tag{4}$$
(*Note*: $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a + b + 2\sqrt{ab}}$.)

We can prove that $f(p)$ is concave on $0 < p < (3 + 2q)/2$. (*Note*: Both $\sqrt{p + 2\sqrt{q}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{3 + 2q - 2p}{3q + 2 - 2p}}$ are concave. Take the second derivative.)

Also, we have
$f(\sqrt{4q}) \ge 0$ and $f(\frac{27q^2 + 3q - 25}{27q - 25})\ge 0$.
Thus, $f(p) \ge 0$ on $[\sqrt{4q}, \frac{27q^2 + 3q - 25}{27q - 25}]$.